# Undefined or Indetermined $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac {e^x - 2 - 5x}{4x^2 + 7x^3} = \text ?$

Tags: limits

I had a problem with this limit

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac {e^x - 2 - 5x}{4x^2 + 7x^3} = \text ?$$

if we try to plug 0, we will get $-1/0$ and by far as I know that was undefined, but I tried to plot it (on online graphing calc) it will be going to $-\infty$, and also on Wolfie said that it is $- \infty$.

Does anybody know why?

Thanks

Comment: Are you asking why $\frac {-1}0$ is often presented as $-\infty$?

Comment: might be, no clue at all :(

Comment: Also check if the denominator $4x^2+7x^3$ is positive near $0$, on both the positive and negative sides.

Answer (score 1):

You have already noticed, by substitution, that the limit in the form $\frac{-1}{0}$ which is not an indeterminate form and which can lead to $\pm \infty$ divergence.

As suggested in the comment all boils down in the sign of the denominator near the value $x=0$ and since

$$4x^2 + 7x^3 = x^2(4+7x) \to 0^+$$

we can conclude for a negative divergence at $-\infty$ since we have a $\frac{-1}{0^+}$ form.

We can also proceed as follows using that eventually $\frac12<-(e^x-2-5x)<\frac 3 2$ and $x^2<4x^2 + 7x^3<11x^2$ and then

$$-\frac{e^x - 2 - 5x}{4x^2 + 7x^3}>\frac{ \frac 12}{11x^2}\to \infty$$